# How to make a reusable function in react?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that does the same thing under 2 difference circumstances inside of if statement but the function has been called in a different module ? what is the best way to handle the issue
I mean I could export the function and import it to the other module but I don't like the idea that I have to call the function ... is there any better design pattern ?

```
// Module
if(somthing is true){
const functionSave =()=>{
// function logic 
}
functionSave()
}
```

```js
      const saveFile = () => {
        if (_miscContext.modal.group === 'a') {
          // change file privlige
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify('a'));
        }
        const ls = JSON.stringify(localStorage);
        
        const downloadBlob = (fileName: string, blob: any) => {
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.target = '_blank';
          link.download = fileName;
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        };
        const blob = new Blob([ls], {
          type: 'text',
        });

        if (_miscContext.modal.group === 'a' || !_miscContext.modal.group) {
          downloadBlob('test', blob);
        } else if (_miscContext.modal.group === 'b') {
          downloadBlob(`test2`, blob);
        }
        // Tracking dowload
        ReactGA.event({
          category: 'Click',
          action: 'Saving File',
        });
        _miscContext.SetModal(false, '', 'preference');
        if (_miscContext.modal.group === 'a') {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify('defualt'));
        }
        return;
      };
```

Comment: I don't understand.... functions are meant to be called, it's how they work. If you want code reuse and reduced duplication then factor it into a utility function and import where you need to use it.

Comment: @DrewReese hi drew , so basically make a separated module for the function (not a functional component) and bring to the needed location ?

Comment: Yes? It's common to create a `/src/utils` directory for common use utility functions. My general rule of thumb is, the 3rd time I define effectively the same functionality, I refactor it into a utility function.

Comment: @DrewReese the problem is the function is related to the component by state and other things and I want to avoid code duplication, the function could have like 10 arguments in my case

Comment: If there is some dependency than please include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are working with. We can't really help debug/fix code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese posted the update

Comment: make the "state" that the function depends on become the parameter of the function.

Comment: to oversimplify what @RickyMo commented, just cram all the parameters into a single obejct, and use it as an interface, without which, the function would just fail

Comment: @Drew Reese If i could ask about the type of the argument in case the argument is a context api state ! And I want to define the type instead of using any … in this case the only logical reason is to export the context interface simply info it to the function to define the argument do you agree with this approach ?